# Any way to run JUnit5 tests in parallel?

Tags: maven, parallel-processing, junit5, selenide

Previously I was using Maven+Selenide+JUnit4 for my tests and it was fine, parallel running worked perfectly. Example:

```
<plugins>
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${maven.surefire.plugin}</version>
    <configuration>
        <parallel>all</parallel>
        <perCoreThreadCount>true</perCoreThreadCount>
        <threadCount>4</threadCount>
        <perCoreThreadCount>false</perCoreThreadCount>
        <redirectTestOutputToFile>true</redirectTestOutputToFile>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

And in Jenkins job I was able to run tests (example below)

```
mvn -Dtest=TestClassName test
```

My tests were running in 4 browsers.

Before I switched to JUnit5, because I would like to use running tests by tags, for example

```
@Test
@Tag("smoke")
public void test1() {}
```

And run all tests which marked as 'smoke' by next command:

```
mvn -Dtag=smoke test
```

But I got next problem: parallel execution does not work and I still did not find solution.
I found this bug https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/issues/1424

How can I run tests in parallel with JUnit5?

I have tried to use in **pom.xml**

```
<forkCount>2</forkCount>
<reuseForks>true</reuseForks>
<parallel>all</parallel>
```

It did not help, I have created a file **junit-platform.properties** and insert there

```
junit.jupiter.execution.parallel.enabled = true
junit.jupiter.execution.parallel.config.strategy = fixed
```

But anyway I was not able to solve this problem.

Comment: Which versions of the different JUnit JARs are you using?

Comment: Hi! I use <junit.jupiter.version>5.2.0</junit.jupiter.version>

Comment: My pom.xml https://github.com/13Dima13/G/blob/master/pom.xml I already switched to latest 5.3.0-M1 version, but anyway I did not get how to run in parallel.

Comment: Have you read the instructions in the User Guide? https://junit.org/junit5/docs/snapshot/user-guide/#writing-tests-parallel-execution

Comment: Of course I have read. Have you checked what I described before? I can not run in parallel

Comment: Where does your `junit-platform.properties` file reside? And can you perhaps share a sample project demonstrating that the tests do not run in parallel?

Comment: Sure, my junit-platform.properties file  https://github.com/13Dima13/G/blob/master/junit-platform.properties

Comment: Any ideas what should I change to run parallel tests?

Comment: Yes, move `junit-platform.properties` to `src/test/resources`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Finally I found solution.

On Maven+JUnit5 parallel execution will work only by classes (not by methods as I get used to have in JUnit4)

How it can be implemented:
Just put these 2 strings in your `pom.xml`:

```
<forkCount>4</forkCount>
<reuseForks>false</reuseForks>
```

Example:

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.22.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <forkCount>4</forkCount>
                <reuseForks>false</reuseForks>
                <properties>
                    <includeTags>${tag}</includeTags>
                </properties>
            </configuration>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-platform-surefire-provider</artifactId>
                    <version>${junit.platform.version}</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
                    <version>${junit.jupiter.version}</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.surefire</groupId>
                    <artifactId>surefire-logger-api</artifactId>
                    <version>${surefire-logger-api}</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
```

For instance you have 3 classes with tests, so after running from console current tests will be created 3 instances of your browser (one for each class) and inside each class tests will be executed by consistently, but classes are executed parallel.

Comment: Thanks for sorting it out! Maven-surefire-plugin 2.22.2 works fine, version 3.0.0-M3 is not working with Junit 5 in our project.

Comment: Hi Gordon Freeman, Can you please how to add fork setting in gralde  project and what is the use of adding it .   <forkCount>4</forkCount>
<reuseForks>false</reuseForks>  
I am using below configuration in junit-platform.properties file, in two browser instants, but i still see some issues
junit.jupiter.execution.parallel.enabled = true
junit.jupiter.execution.parallel.mode.default = same_thread
junit.jupiter.execution.parallel.mode.classes.default = concurrent
junit.jupiter.execution.parallel.config.strategy=fixed
junit.jupiter.execution.parallel.config.fixed.parallelism=2

Comment: This was helpful for running `RestAssured` in parallel since `RestAssured` relies on a static configuration which can not be easily shared between threads.